# ComboBox Initial Binding

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, combobox

I have a small problem with binding a `ComboBox` to a `SelectedValue` and keep the inital value at `null`.

I am using WPF with .NET 4.5.2.

Now the thing is I got a `ComboBox` a bound `ItemsSource` with a couple of entries (not including `null`) and a bound `SelectedValue`. The binding itself works just fine, but in some cases I want the inital value of the `SelectedValue` to be `null`. The value stored in the bound property is `null`. But once the binding is created, the `ComboBox` first fetches the `null` value and then Updates it to the first value in the list.

To be seen in this log:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=34124640) for Binding (hash=55728099)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'SelectedIncomingPort'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=34124640): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.SelectedValue (hash=38686306)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=34124640): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=34124640): Found data context element: ComboBox (hash=38686306) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=34124640): Activate with root item UIPathNode (hash=12632436)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=34124640):   At level 0 using cached accessor for UIPathNode.SelectedIncomingPort: RuntimePropertyInfo(SelectedIncomingPort)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=34124640): Replace item at level 0 with UIPathNode (hash=12632436), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(SelectedIncomingPort)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=34124640): GetValue at level 0 from UIPathNode (hash=12632436) using RuntimePropertyInfo(SelectedIncomingPort): <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=34124640): TransferValue - got raw value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 83 : BindingExpression (hash=34124640): TransferValue - null-value conversion produced <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=34124640): TransferValue - using final value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 90 : BindingExpression (hash=34124640): Update - got raw value NodePort (hash=28905541)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 93 : BindingExpression (hash=34124640): Update - implicit converter produced NodePort (hash=28905541)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 94 : BindingExpression (hash=34124640): Update - using final value NodePort (hash=28905541)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 102 : BindingExpression (hash=34124640): SetValue at level 0 to UIPathNode (hash=12632436) using RuntimePropertyInfo(SelectedIncomingPort): NodePort (hash=28905541)
```

The last 4 lines show the update I did not expect. I am able to set the value to `null` after the init of the binding, but it overwrites the inital value and that is something I do not want.

The binding itself is pretty straight forward:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding IncomingPorts}" MinWidth="150"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedIncomingPort, Mode=TwoWay, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
    ToolTip="{Binding SelectedIncomingPort.PatchedPortTitle, Converter={StaticResource EmptyStringToNullConverter}, FallbackValue={x:Null}}"
    Style="{DynamicResource PortComboBox}" />
```

The property behind is pretty simple too:

```
Public Property SelectedIncomingPort As API.IUIPathNodePort Implements API.IUIPathNode.SelectedIncomingPort
  Get
    Return _node.SelectedIncomingPort
  End Get
  Set(value As API.IUIPathNodePort)
    If Object.Equals(_node.SelectedIncomingPort, value) Then
      Return
    End If

    _node.SelectedIncomingPort = value
    NotifyPropertyChanged(Function() SelectedIncomingPort)
  End Set
End Property
```

The problem is that I do not understand why this update is fired. And I don't know how I can prevent it.

I tried the flipping the definition of `ItemSource` and `SelectedItem` without any luck and I tried adding `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` with all allowed values without any success.

The problem is that I don't know when and if the bindings are created because the `ComboBox` is stored on a `VirtualizingStackPanel` and is only created once the user actually views it.

Does anyone have a idea how I could solve this? I only want the ComboBox to stick with the original value.